# Pgfplots: Generate points randomly

Tags: pgfplots, plot, foreach, random

I have a very simple `pgf` plot, like this:

```
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      height=4cm,
      width=.8\textwidth,
  xlabel=Observable,
  ylabel=Number of Events,
      samples=100,
      domain=-1:3,
      ticks=none,
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      enlarge y limits=true,
    ]
    \addplot[black,no marks] {exp(-x)};
    \addplot[red,no marks] {0.3*gauss(0,0.2) + exp(-x)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I would like to add a new data row with randomly generated data points with the following properties:

- They should be equidistant in `x`, with a distance that I can choose
- They should scatter around the red line in `y`, with a deviation that I can choose
- They should have error bars that always correspond to +/- the square root of the value.

I suppose this can be achieved with some `foreach` magic in `pgfplots`, but I'm unsure as to what is the most elegant way to achieve this.

I would like to avoid having to generate the points with an external script (which I can of course do), but would rather have everything done with pgf directly.

Comment: Take a look at the pgf manual, section 90.3, Pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: @Huang_d: yes, that is very helpful already. but how do I make all these numbers into a data set that I can plot?

Comment: It might actually be a lot easier to make those points externally, using say in  R or python and then just plot them. Generating points via math in tikz is fairly slow. Also have the advantage that the plot does not change each time you recompile.

Comment: @daleif: I understand your argument and think it is valid, but I would still like to know how to do it with plain `pgf` as well. The document needs to be very portable, so relying on any type of shell-redirect or `Makefile` is not so nice.

Comment: The `gauss` function isn't standard, can you turn your snippet into a complete example with the necessary definitions?

Comment: To expand on what @Huang_d said. As `rand` makes a pseudo-random number between -1 and 1, you can use e.g. `\addplot[only marks,blue,mark=*,mark size=1pt] {0.3*gauss(0,0.2) + exp(-x) + 0.5*rand};` to plot the same as the red curve, but adding a number between -0.5 and 0.5. Some more work is needed for the error bar though.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. indeed. I added the missing definition to the snippet. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: The point is not to have the graph redone externally every time. But to generate the data points as a static data file. That only have to be made once.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'm going with your solution now. For the error bars, I'm using `error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y fixed relative=0.015` - this is not exactly what I want, since the error bars should rather be the square root of the value, but for now it's good enough I think.

Comment: I'm left to wonder, the square root of which value, exactly? Because 1.5% is *much* less than the square root of the y-value. Did you mean the square root of the random deviation?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. In principle the square root of the y-value, but I would probably shift the whole thing by some constant to a y-range where the error bars look reasonable then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the random number functions `rnd` and `rand` directly in an `\addplot` expression. `rand` makes a pseudo random number between -1 and 1, so you can use something like

```
\addplot[only marks,blue,mark=*,mark size=1pt] {0.3*gauss(0,0.2) + exp(-x) + 0.5*rand};
```

to make the noisy plot. As you mention `pgfplots` has a method for making an error bar relative to the function value, so you can do something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,
               tikz]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      height=4cm,
      width=.8\textwidth,
      xlabel=Observable,
      ylabel=Number of Events,
      samples=100,
      domain=-1:3,
      ticks=none,
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      enlarge y limits=true,
    ]
    \addplot[black,no marks] {exp(-x)};
    \addplot[red,no marks]  {0.3*gauss(0,0.2) + exp(-x)};

    \addplot[
       only marks,
       blue,
       mark=*,
       mark size=0.7pt,
       error bars/.cd,
         y dir=both,
         y fixed relative=0.1] {0.3*gauss(0,0.2) + exp(-x) + 0.5*rand};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## More general

(There may well be much better ways of doing this.) You can make a table of numbers from scratch using `pgfplotstable`. That allows you to generate the function and the noise separately, and calculate whatever error you want. It is a bit verbose, and it also takes some time to compile, so daleif's suggestion of making the datafiles elsewhere is probably good.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,
               tikz]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\tikzset{
declare function={
 gauss(\m,\s,\x)={1/(\s*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((\x-\m)^2)/(2*\s^2))};
}
}

\pgfplotstableset{
 create on use/index/.style={create col/set list={0,...,99}}
}
% make a new table with 100 rows,  populate 
\pgfplotstablenew[columns={index}]{100}{\datatable}

% make an x-column
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  create col/assign/.code={
    % calculate expression
    \pgfmathparse{(\thisrow{index}/\pgfplotstablerows)*4-1}
    % save to table
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\pgfmathresult
}
]{x}{\datatable}

% make a y-column without random noise
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  create col/assign/.code={
    \pgfmathparse{0.3*gauss(0,0.2,\thisrow{x}) + exp(-\thisrow{x})}
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\pgfmathresult
}
]{y}{\datatable}
% make random noise
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  create col/assign/.code={
    \pgfmathparse{0.2*rand}
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\pgfmathresult
}
]{ynoise}{\datatable}

% error, as square root of absolute value
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  create col/assign/.code={
    \pgfmathparse{sqrt(abs(\thisrow{ynoise}))}
    \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}\pgfmathresult
}
]{yerr}{\datatable}

\begin{document}
%\pgfplotstabletypeset\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      height=4cm,
      width=.8\textwidth,
      xlabel=Observable,
      ylabel=Number of Events,
      samples=100,
      domain=-1:3,
      ticks=none,
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      enlarge y limits=true,
    ]
    \addplot[black,no marks] {exp(-x)};
    \addplot[red,no marks] table[x=x,y=y] {\datatable};

    \addplot[
       only marks,
       blue,mark=*,
       mark size=0.5pt,
       error bars/.cd,
         y dir=both,
         y explicit]
    table[x=x,y expr=\thisrow{y}+\thisrow{ynoise},y error=yerr] {\datatable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```