# How to change coordinates in axis scale?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to build a simple 1-dimension random walk. I use \foreach and want to do an increment of a x (to a step) and y (to an epsilon).

```
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=2018, xmax=2040,
        ymin=0, ymax=200,
        xlabel={$year$}, ylabel={$value$},
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=center]

        \coordinate (start) at (axis cs:2018,100);
        \foreach \year in {2018,...,2040}  {
            \coordinate (next) at ($ (start) + (1, rand*5) $);
            \draw[red] (start) -- (next);   
            \coordinate (start) at (next);
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have an error "Dimension too large". If I set a dimension (e.g. cm) to the line

```
\coordinate (next) at ($ (start) + (0.5cm, rand*0.5cm) $);
```

Then the code works fine but the step is not relevant to axis anymore. Is there a way to make xshift equal one step on the axis withouth hardcoding axis width in cm and specifying the corresponding xshift in cm as well?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem. Just edit your question and add missing code, preamble etc...

Comment: Might be better to generate a table of values in advance, and plot those, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373940/pgfplots-generate-points-randomly/373964#373964

Comment: @TorbjørnT. this example looks really good and fits my task perfectly since I want to reuse noise values for the second plot. Thank you, I will try to go this way.

Comment: By the way, an unrelated comment: Neither `year` nor `value` are mathematical expressions, so don't write them in math mode. Use `xlabel={year}, ylabel={value}`.  (Unless of course you use an actual variable, and not the words.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`axis cs` allows only absolute position. If you need relative positions you have to use the `axis direction cs`. For more information see section "4.17.1 Accessing Axis Coordinates in Graphical Elements" in the documentation of pgfplots.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=2018, xmax=2040,
    ymin=0, ymax=200,
    xlabel={year}, ylabel={value},
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=center
  ]
%
    \coordinate (start) at (2018,100);
    \foreach \year in {2018,...,2040}
      \draw[red](start) -- + (axis direction cs:1, rand*5)coordinate(start);
%
    \coordinate (start) at (2018,100);
    \draw[blue](start) foreach \year in {2018,...,2040}
      {-- ++ (axis direction cs:1, rand*5)coordinate(start)};
%
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]